strange reverse proxy behaviour (different on lan and wan)
I'm becoming crazy with my reverse proxy, any help would be much appreciated :)
I host my own servers, firewall is pfsense. port 80 & 443 are forwarded from home box via nat translation to a reverse proxy (Apache) which redirect traffic to different internal server.
I have many services, redirect is working fine.
Great !
I've configured pfsense, to redirect LAN call to the reverse proxy (with DNS resolver), WAN are redirected to my box through Cloudflare.
Now the strange part, when I'm on local network, everything work as expected.
If I point to my.url/notavailableurl I got a 404 error. That's what I want. (no ending slash)
If I point to my.url/notavailableurl/ I got a 404 error. That's what I want. (ending slash)
When I'm on the WAN network :
If I point to my.url/notavailableurl I got a 404 error. That's what I want. (no ending slash)
If I point to my.url/notavailableurl/ I'm redirected to 10.10.10.1/notavailableurl/ with a ressource not found error, where 10.10.10.1 is the local ip of the server hosting the website.
It seems to have issue with the ending slash, however I don't understand why I have no issue on LAN
My apache config is pretty simple,
I've tried lot of things, nothing seems to work
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks !
    <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerAdmin me@me.me
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
ServerName me.me
ServerAlias www.me.me


<Directory />
          Options FollowSymLinks
          AllowOverride None
          Require all denied
</Directory>


<Directory /usr/share>
          AllowOverride None
          Require all granted
</Directory>


<Directory /var/www/>
          Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
          AllowOverride None
          Require all granted
</Directory>
ProxyRequests Off

#jellyfin
<Location /jelly/socket>
      ProxyPreserveHost On
      ProxyPass "ws://IP:8096/jelly/socket"
      ProxyPassReverse "ws://IP:8096/jelly/socket"
</Location>
<Location /jelly>
     ProxyPass "http://IP:8096/medias"
      ProxyPassReverse "http://IP:8096/jelly"
</Location>
#/jellyfin

#guacamole
  <Location /guacamole/>
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
      ProxyPass http://IP:8080/guacamole/ flushpackets=on
      ProxyPassReverse http://IP:8080/guacamole/
  </Location>
<Location /guacamole/websocket-tunnel>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    ProxyPass ws://IP:8080/guacamole/websocket-tunnel
    ProxyPassReverse ws://IP:8080/guacamole/websocket-tunnel
</Location>
#/guacamole                                                                                                                                                  
#qbitorrent
<Location /torrent>
  Deny from all                       
      Allow from LOCAL_NET 
</Location>
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteRule             ^/torrent$      "/torrent/$1" [R]
        ProxyPass "/torrent/" "http://IP:8080/"
        ProxyPassReverse "/torrent" "http://IP:8080/"
#/qbitorrent


#everything else

        ProxyPass "/"  "http://IP/"
        ProxyPassReverse "/"  "http://IP/"




SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/me.me/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/me.me/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>

